# Getting Execute before finishing the task Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ui-thread

Hi I'm running the Asynctask in my activity and getting the data from the server. In `onPostExecute`  metod I'm inserting the data in Database now I want to pass those ids in two different fragments I'm passing the the ids by following code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray(BConstant.TAXONOMY_TID, dbtids);
    bundle.putStringArray(BConstant.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAMES,
            dblistProCategory);
    ProductCategoryFragment.newInstance(bundle);

    // ProductDetailsFragment
    Bundle bundleForProductList = new Bundle();
    bundleForProductList
            .putStringArray(BConstant.TAXONOMY_TID, dbtids);
    bundleForProductList.putString(BConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES,
            cookie);
    bundleForProductList.putStringArray(
            BConstant.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAMES, dblistProCategory);
    ProductListFragment.newInstance(bundleForProductList);
```

But above lines of code get executed before the AsyncTask fininshed. but i have written this line `new CategoryFrag().execute();` above this code. what should i do.

#### Edited

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            try {
                listItems
                        .add(result.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString(BConstant.NAME_CONSTANT)
                                .toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        listProCategory = listItems.toArray(new String[0]);
  returnsTID = saDatabaseHandler.getProductCategoryTID();
        for (int i = 0; i < tids.length; i++) {
            if (!returnsTID.contains(tids[i])) {
                saDatabaseHandler.insertProductCategoryData(
                        tids[i], listProCategory[i]);
                
            }
        }
        getOfflineData();
  }
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.ProductListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-02 11 :41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:154)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:141)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at com.abc.xyz.ProductCategoryFragment$DisplayProductCategoryListArrayAdapter.<init>(ProductCategoryFragment.java:175)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at com.abc.xyz.ProductCategoryFragment.onActivityCreated(ProductCategoryFragment.java:113)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1017)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1804)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
    02-02 11:41:00.451: E/AndroidRuntime(20901):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: move all the code to `onPostExecute`

Comment: @Raghunandan Exception is coming

Comment: @Raghunandan let me clear the question i am passing the ids by calling the above code in fragments. So first i want to finish the AsyncTask of activity class then only i want to start the fragment class code.

Comment: this code is inside onPost ?

Comment: @Amrola no but i have tried in onPostExecute  too.

Comment: @Raghunandan i want to wait the next line of code until Asynctask get finish. what should i do. in activity class.

Comment: @Amrola same problem before completing the async task of activity class fragmnet class trying to get the ids

Comment: post your logcat , so we could see whats wrong ? 
and post your asynctask code

Comment: @Amrola please chekc my Edited code

Comment: what is the code at line in 113 in ProductCategoryFragment

Comment: adapter = new DisplayProductCategoryListArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
    dblistProCategory, dbimgBitmapUrls);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46621/discussion-between-amrola-and-user3154663)

Comment: @user3154663 what is line 175 `ProductCategoryFragment.java`? Sonmething on that line is null. Post the relevant code so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

call a method defined in your activity from your `onPostExecute` method. And write the above code inside that method.

If the async task is in another class, the pass context to the async task, and in the `onPostExecute` method after fetching data from the db, do this:

```
((YourCallingActivity)mContext).methodName();
```